# SQL Server : ROW_NUMBER() OVER on table variable to amend duplicate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, row-number

Lets say I have table variable declared like so...

```
DECLARE @LocalTable TABLE
(
    IdField NVARCHAR(MAX),
    NameField NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

And I populate it like so...

```
INSERT INTO @LocalTable
SELECT
    IdColumn,
    NameColumn
FROM SourceTable
```

`NameColumn` in the source table may have duplicate values, and therefore `NameField` in the local table will have the same duplicate values.

And let's say I want to insert the local table into a target table like so...

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (NewIdColumn, NewNameColumn)
    SELECT
        IdField,
        NameField
    FROM 
        @LocalTable
```

BUT: `NewNameColumn` in `TargetTable` has a `UNIQUE` constraint, and so duplicates cause an exception.

I want to apply this example,

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NameField ORDER BY NameField)
```

Such that the `NameField` is appended/suffixed with a number digit indicating its duplication.

I have this working example that can select correctly appended values, but I cannot get this to work in an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE localtable 
SET NameField = AppendedNameField 
FROM @LocalTable AS localtable

SELECT 
    CONCAT(Ref.NameField, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ref.NameField 
                                             ORDER BY Source.IdField)), *
FROM 
    @LocalTable AS Source
INNER JOIN 
    @LocalTable AS Ref ON Ref.NameField = Source.NameField  
                       AND Ref.IdField != Source.IdField
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a reason you cannot select distinct?  If so, you need to make a decision what data you want to load, and use aggregate functions or other methods to get your data

Comment: You can do many things here - select distinct, use row_number and potentially prefer one over another, and also add index to ignore duplicate keys. You need to add some considerations so the answer will be meaningful..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I have understood what you are trying to do.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
CONCAT(NameField, ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER(PARTITION BY NameField ORDER BY IdField)) AS NewName, *
FROM @LocalTable
)
UPDATE
CTE SET Name = NewName
```

If you only want to do it to duplicated names you can add a `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name)` into the CTE and conditional logic using that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to update the table, couldn't you just add the suffix when inserting?

```
DECLARE @LocalTable TABLE (IdField INT, NameField VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @LocalTable VALUES (1, 'Not Duplicate'), (2, 'Duplicate'), (3, 'Duplicate');

INSERT INTO TargetTable (NewIdColumn, NewNameColumn)
SELECT  IdField,
        CONCAT(NameField, 
            CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NameField) > 1 
                THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NameField ORDER BY IdField) 
                ELSE '' 
            END)
FROM    @LocalTable
ORDER BY IdField;
```

Alternatively, you can update by simply wrapping the above select in a subquery, and updating that:

```
DECLARE @LocalTable TABLE (IdField INT, NameField VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @LocalTable VALUES (1, 'Not Duplicate'), (2, 'Duplicate'), (3, 'Duplicate');

UPDATE  t
SET     NameField = NewNameField
FROM    
(
    SELECT  IdField, NameField,
            NewNameField = CONCAT(NameField, 
                                CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NameField) > 1 
                                    THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NameField ORDER BY IdField) 
                                    ELSE '' 
                                END)
    FROM    @LocalTable
) AS t;

SELECT * FROM @LocalTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an identity field to the temp table.

```
DECLARE @LocalTable TABLE
(
ix int identity primary key,
IdField NVARCHAR(MAX),
NameField NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

Insert into @LocalTable(IdColumn, NameColumn)
SELECT
IdColumn,
NameColumn
FROM SourceTable
-- Make sure same names are consecutive in the table
ORDER BY NameColumn
```

The set NameColumn like so:

```
update lt set 
NameColumn = NameColumn 
-- Add a number based on the ix, minus the lowest ix entry for the same name
+ cast(
    (select lt.ix - min(lt2.ix) + 1
    from @localTable lt2 where lt2.name = lt.name) 
as nvarchar(10))
from @LocalTable lt
-- Only do those with duplicated names
where lt.NameColumn in (
  select NameColumn from @localtable group by NameColumn having count(1) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, consider using Temp table instead of temp variable.
Second, try to change NVARCHAR(MAX) by something smaller, like INT
Here is the code to include only unique values in the NameField:

```
CREATE TABLE #LocalTable 
(
    IdField NVARCHAR(MAX),
    NameField NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #LocalTable
VALUES (1,'A'), (2,'B'), (3,'B')

INSERT INTO TargetTable
(
    NewIdColumn,
    NewNameColumn
)
SELECT IdField, NameField
FROM #LocalTable 
WHERE IdField in (
    SELECT MIN(IdField) FROM #LocalTable 
    GROUP BY NameField
);
```

Be aware that "IdField" of duplicate records will be ignored and not inserted into target table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
WITH TargetTable AS(
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ref.NameField ORDER BY Source.IdField) AS UniqueID

FROM @LocalTable AS L
),
UpdatedData AS(
    SELECT Source.NameField, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ref.NameField ORDER BY Source.IdField) AS UniqueID,
           CONCAT(Ref.NameField, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ref.NameField ORDER BY Source.IdField)) AS AppendedNameField
    FROM @LocalTable AS Source
    INNER JOIN @LocalTable AS Ref ON Ref.NameField = Source.NameField AND Ref.IdField != Source.IdField
)
UPDATE T
SET NameField=U.AppendedNameField
FROM TargetTable AS T
JOIN UpdatedData AS U ON T.NameField=U.NameField AND T.UniqueID=U.UniqueID;
```